# Delete partitions

Tags: partitioning, windows-10

How do I know which partition I can delete? There are about 8 partitons in my hdd (i was wrongly trying to install linux) but I just want Windows' partition now.

Comment: I don't see your issue as on-topic (it's not about Ubuntu - https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) but I would ensure your wanted OS controls the booting (if you delete a partition that boots your system, it won't boot any longer), then from that wanted OS, remove the unwanted partitions.  You delete any partitions not used by your wanted OS, which is not Ubuntu as you've written it, thus off-topic as I read your question.

Comment: sorry for asking off topic I didn't know which one was right (which one is it?), anyway, thanks for the answer, I'll take a look at the windows partition

Comment: There is no specific order to partitions (which change depending on what OS/release(s) are installed, in which order, and details we do not know). In your situation, I may boot your unwanted OSes to note what partitions they use, then boot the one you want to keep, and ensure they aren't used by that OS (can you recognize the partitions used by the other OSes? and they're not used?), then delete from there (if not used) **providing** you've ensured that OS controls the machine booting (so as to not end up at grub rescue or other fail-to-boot scenario).

Comment: I recognized the partition that Windows is instaled, I'm gonna delete the others now. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can first delete the NTFS primary partition. Then delete the EFI system partition (usually 100 MB) and then ddelete the Recovery partition. Windows created partitions will now be removed and also the windows boot manager.

Comment: What? OP said *"I just want Windows' partition now"*.